Настройка 2FA ADFS в NEXTCLOUD
Стоит задача настроить 2FA ADFS в NEXTCLOUD.
В официальной документации не нашёл полной инструкции для настройки 2FA ADFS.
Настраивал с помощью форумов и интернета.
Не могу понять ошибку "Пользователь не является членом требуемой группы". Если авторизовываюсь через "логин и пароль", то пользователь состоит в группе.
Можете подсказать, где я ошибаюсь?
Прикладываю скриншот настройки "Подтверждения подлинности".



При попытка авторизоваться через 2FA, спрашивает "ввести логин и пароль", после ввода данных ошибка "notPermitted"

Вот информация с журнала NEXTCLOUD.

